# Django post_save signal's instance datetime field

Tags: django, datetime, signals, unicode-string

I found interesting detail and can't find note about it in Django docs.

In post_save handler there is the instance object. In my case, when `created is True`, this instance has datetime field, but value of this field is unicode string instead of datetime value. 
And if I reload object from database, this field will contain correct datetime value.

I'm curious, is it correct behavior or I've missed error in my code?

Comment: Can we see your code?

Comment: this is definitely not the correct behaviour. what django version are you running, and yes, can we see your code? what does the unicode string contain?